# Extends error in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

Hi All While i am executing the below code and getting this

> "VM490:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: _super is not defined" in Typescript

Code :

```js
class Animal {
      constructor(name, speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.name = name;
      }

    }

    // Inherit from Animal
class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor(name, speed) {
    super(name, speed);             
  }

}

(function(){
   var rabbit = new Rabbit("White Rabbit", 10);
   console.log(rabbit);
})();
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(public%20name%3A%20string%2C%20public%20speed%3A%20number)%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Rabbit%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20speed%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(name%2C%20speed)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A(function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20rabbit%20%3D%20new%20Rabbit(%22White%20Rabbit%22%2C%2010)%3B%0D%0A%09console.log(rabbit)%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B

Comment: me neither - i edited your post and added the snippet and as u can see it's working - therefore you have another error in your script

Comment: There is no `_super` in the posted code. It is valid JavaScript code but not valid TypeScript code; the properties `speed` and `name` must be declared in `class Animal`

Comment: Alternatively you can declare `class Animal { constructor(public name, public speed) { } }` to be valid TS. The compiler generates the JS declaration of `class Animal` you already have now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/susantadas/o4hLhwro/5/  -  We can follow the above url and i am getting below error  :                                 Uncaught ReferenceError: _super is not defined
    at new Rabbit (eval at exec (VM719 typescript.js:41), <anonymous>:12:9)
    at eval (eval at exec (VM719 typescript.js:41), <anonymous>:18:18)
    at eval (eval at exec (VM719 typescript.js:41), <anonymous>:20:3)
    at exec (VM719 typescript.js:41)
    at HTMLDocument.runScripts (VM719 typescript.js:41)